# Measuring happiness in Children

Tags: happiness

I am in a cross cultural, multilingual setting.  I would like to measure happiness / frustration of children before and after changing rules about food and water before surgical operations are performed.  What suggestions would you have for measuring happiness in both verbal and non-verbal children (verbal children may not speak English)?  I would prefer a type of visual analog scale to be answered by the child if able and the parent.

Answer (score 2):

Try the World Database of Happiness, if you haven't already.

https://worlddatabaseofhappiness.eur.nl/collections/measures-of-happiness/what-is-this-collection-measures-of-happiness/

There is a collection of validated 'happiness' measures here.

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Very good pointer. +1